# JAVA- error: cannot find symbol -- haven't found answer on site yet

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a code for class that is supposed to take exam scores as inputs until the user inputs '-1'. After they quit, it averages the scores and prints it. I keep getting a 'cannot find symbol' error, and I've looked through the site and haven't found anything applicable yet.

```
import java.util.*;

public class hw6
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int avg = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println("This program will intake exam scores between 0 and 100 ONLY.");
    System.out.println("Enter scores to average, and when you're done inputting, ");
    System.out.println("enter -1 to stop and average your scores.");
    int scoreIn = in.nextInt;
    getLegalInput(scoreIn);
    System.out.println("The average of the exam scores is " + avg + ".");


 }

 public static int getLegalInput (int scoreIn)
 {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (scoreIn != -1)
    {
            if ((scoreIn < 101) && (scoreIn > -1))
            {
            sum = (sum + scoreIn);
            i++;
            }
    else
    System.out.println("Out of range! Must be between 0 and 100.");
    }
    if (scoreIn == -1)
    {
      CalcAvg(sum, i);
    }
}
public static int CalcAvg(int sum, int i)
{
    int avg = 0;

    i = (i - 1); //fix problem where the stop value is included in the i value
    //calc = (calc - Svalue); // fixes problem where stop value throws off the calc
    avg = (sum/i); //averages the values of exam

    return (avg);
}
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
hw6.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        int scoreIn = in.nextInt;
                    ^
  symbol:   variable nextInt
  location: variable in of type Scanner
1 error
```

All help and advice is appreciated!

Comment: Oh my god i cant believe i missed something that lame. Thank you

Comment: Your code will not compile after fixing in.nextInt(). Add return statement in the method !!

Answer (score 2):

[`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) is a method, not a data member - it should be called with parentheses: `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Mureinik is correct. When ever you get compile time error or run time exceptions in any java program you write, just try to see what is the message mentioned by the error or exception log. In the case mentioned by you clearly it says

```
hw6.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        int scoreIn = in.nextInt;
                    ^
  symbol:   variable nextInt
  location: variable in of type Scanner
1 error
```

1. Issue is at line number 14 :see the line number in the code you are
   compiling.
2. What is the issue ? : `cannot find symbol`
3. Which symbol is not found ? : `nextInt`
4. In which java class the symbol is not found ? : `Scanner.java`

So the issue is : `In Scanner.java there is no variable of type nextInt. We have written the code which tries to access nextInt variable from the object of class Scanner.`

Correct search on internet should be verifying about this variable and then you would have got to know that this is not a variable but a method(function
) so instead of writing `in.nextInt` it should be `in.nextInt()`

Also notice that in Java we call functions as methods. When ever you wish to get some process done, like in current case we wish to read an Integer from the input stream, we always get it done using methods. Usually we only access constants variables from objects of another class. For interacting with objects from other class we should use methods. We do not expose non constants fields outside the class [java syntax allows but as good practice we expose methods as interface to outside world]. This relates to `Encapsulation`. 
Hope this helps in your future coding.